# Error editing ticket when mooving app on a NAS with Linux Debian

Tags: linux

I mooved a app with mysql+java+play!framework on a NAS (Linux Debian), mostly is working but when i want to create a ticket for printing i have this error:

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: app\fr\boutique\web\reports\reparationReport.jrxml (No such file or directory)

(all is working good when app installed in local with windows)

Part of file Generator.java:

```
public static InputStream generateReparation(long id) {

    // - Paramètres de connexion à la base de données
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/bddbc";
    String login = "root";
    String password = "root";
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // - Connexion à la base
        Driver monDriver = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(monDriver);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);

        // - Chargement et compilation du rapport
       JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("app\\fr\\boutique\\web\\reports\\reparationReport.jrxml");
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

        // - Paramètres à envoyer au rapport
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        parameters.put("CURRENT_PATH", "app\\fr\\boutique\\web\\reports");
        parameters.put("idReparation", id);

        System.out.println("Id = " + id);

        // - Execution du rapport
        JasperPrint jrprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, connection);

        // - Création du rapport au format PDF
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jrprint, os);
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(((ByteArrayOutputStream) os).toByteArray());

    } catch (JRException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
             connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong directory separator in your paths. Linux uses a forward slash (`/`) to delimit directories, not a backslash (`\`).